# Any alternative for FlexBoxLayout in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am creating Flexboxlayout in android native app but now i am create flutter app. I am not able to make flexboxlayout alternative in flutter.

By using Row widget is it possible?

Currenty in row it not goes to below it show "A RenderFlex overflowed by 319 pixels on the right." error.

[image]

please see marked section in image i need this type of layout. if one row full then it show in second and second complete then it show in third row.

Comment: give a proper height of its parent widget or wrap under expanded widget to overcome the overflow issue.

Comment: if "marked" sections are black rectangles with  those child "chips" them use [Wrap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately , we don't have any such a layout option in Flutter for now .

but if you want to achieve your shown screenshots results you can use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tags plugin , it will provide you those chips .

Comment: Please check edited question, I attached screen shot.